# Detect bottom value in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception

I've written a haskell function which splits a list `xs` into `(init xs, last xs)` like so:

```
split xs = split' [] xs
    where
        split' acc (x:[]) = (reverse acc, x)
        split' acc (x:xs) = split' (x:acc) xs
```

Since an empty list can not be split in this way, there is no match for the empty list. However, I did not want to simply `error ...` the function. Thus I defined the following:

```
split [] = ([], undefined)
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation I can thus define a safe `init` which simply returns the empty list for the empty list:

```
init' = fst . split
```

Is there some way how I could detect the undefined if I tried to access it, such that

```
last' xs
  | isUndefined (snd xs) = ...
  | otherwise            = ...
```

I do know about `Maybe` and `Either`, and that those are a better choice for expressing what I want. However I wondered if there is a way to detect an actual value of undefined, i.e. in terms of catching errors, like catching exceptions.

Comment: The simple answer is NO.  It's not possible to detect undefined.  (A more complicated answer is that you can catch exceptions in the IO momad, but that's not what you want to do here.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because bottom subsumes non-termination, the function `isUndefined` would have to solve the halting problem and thus cannot exist.

But note that even if it existed, you still could not tell if the undefined value in the 2nd element of your tuple was put there through your `split` function or if the last element of the list was already undefined.

Comment: If a function existed that solved the halting problem, we could show False, and therefore, we could show everything, including "we can tell if the undefined value in the 2nd element of your tuple was put there through your split function or if the last element of the list was already undefined."

Answer (score 11):

`undefined` is no better than using `error`. In fact, `undefined` in Prelude is [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Err.html#undefined) as

```
undefined =  error "Prelude.undefined"
```

Now, a function that can't result in an `error` is called a "total function", i.e. it is valid for all input values.

The `split` function you've currently implemented has the signature

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], a)
```

This is a problem, since the type signature promises that the result always contains a list and an element, which is clearly impossible to provide for empty lists of generic type.

The canonical way in Haskell to address this is to change the type signature to signify that sometimes we don't have a valid value for the second item.

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], Maybe a)
```

Now you can write a proper implementation for the case where you get an empty list

```
split [] = ([], Nothing)
split xs = split' [] xs
    where
        split' acc (x:[]) = (reverse acc, Just x)
        split' acc (x:xs) = split' (x:acc) xs
```

Now you can detect the missing value case by pattern-matching

```
let (init', last') = split xs
in case last' of
    Nothing -> ... -- do something if we don't have a value
    Just x  -> ... -- do something with value x
```

Comment: A bit ironic that undefined is defined ;)

Comment: @DanBurton Well, if that's your kind of humor, note that it's also possible to define `undefined` like this: `undefined = undefined`.  It behaves different (this definition doesn't terminate when forced), but semantically, it has the same value (bottom).

Answer (score 8):

The `error` function doesn't do anything until it is evaluated, so you can do something like:

```
split [] = ([], error "split: empty list")

last' = snd . split
```

Comment: The best answer here, in my opinion, because it answers the next question scravy would have had anyway: "What do I put in the `otherwise` clause?".

Comment: I do know this, as I said “thanks to lazy evaluation” - putting error is like putting undefined in there. I wanted to detect this very thing, but as I've learned that’s quite not possible since the semantics of bottom forbid it.

Comment: +1 for using `error` with an informative message. OP's choice of "I did not want to `error ...`" and using `undefined` mostly leads to frustration when debugging: "Yes, I hit `undefined`; but *which usage* of `undefined`?". This is especially bad in (GHC) Haskell, since laziness and aggressive optimisation can make a compiled program execute in an unexpected order. Stack traces have recently been added to GHC, but they're still opt-in and kind of an illusion rather than a true record of how the binary actually executes. Far easier to just tell us what went wrong in the first place!

Answer (score 4):

From the [Haskell 2010 Language Report > Introduction # Values and Types](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-120001.3)

> Errors in Haskell are semantically equivalent to ⊥ (“bottom”). Technically, they are indistinguishable from nontermination, so the language includes no mechanism for detecting or acting upon errors.

To be clear, `undefined` is intended to be a way to insert ⊥ into your program, and given that (as shang noted) `undefined` is defined in terms of `error`, there is, therefore, "no mechanism for detecting or acting upon `undefined`".

Comment: While this is correct from a Haskell 2010 point of view, it's worth noting that in GHC Haskell, some ⊥ values, including `error` are implemented as exceptions, which may be caught in the `IO` monad. However, doing so is usually indicative of bad design, as there are better ways of handling errors in pure code. (There is even a `NonTermination` exception which may be thrown when the runtime can detect non-termination, though this is of course not reliable due to the halting problem).

Answer (score 3):

Although semantically speaking Ingo's answer is correct, if you're using GHC, there is a way using a couple of "unsafe" functions that, although not quite perfect as if you pass it a computation of type IO a which contains an exception it will return True, works. It's a bit of a cheat though :).

```
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Unsafe.Coerce

isUndefined :: a -> Bool
isUndefined x = unsafePerformIO $ catch ((unsafeCoerce x :: IO ()) >> return False) (const $ return True :: SomeException -> IO Bool)
```

I know this is horrible, but none the less it works. It won't detect non termination though ;)

Comment: This can be improved on by replace "return False" by something like "(\e -> return $ show e == "Prelude.undefined")" to pretty much 100% accuracy in practice (unless somebody creates an exception who's implementation of show return "Prelude.undefined", but that would be silly...)

Comment: `isUndefined "bla"` produces an `internal error: stg_ap_v_ret` on all GHC versions I've tried it with (GHC-7.0 and up). The problem seems to be the use of `unsafeCoerce` here.